# rails, heroku devise action mailer not working - how to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, gmail, actionmailer

i am trying to set up confirmable with heroku devise for my app. here is my code: (followed a few tutorials)

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'myapp.herokuapp.com' }
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'myapp.herokuapp.com'

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

i've added the heroku variables for the password/domain/username. but when i try to sign-up on my live site, i get an error.

does anybody see any errors? or can someone point me on how I can debug this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Heroku & Gmail have some authentication token problem while sending e-mail.

It is better to use [sendgrid](https://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid) or [Mandrill by MailChimp](https://addons.heroku.com/mandrill)

They both are free & configuration is very easy